# How to get the hashmap returned from a resteasy web service?

Tags: java, resteasy

I like to return a hashmap object from a rest easy web service.. but I can't get the hashmap object from the client(in my case.. it is a managed bean). When I try to get that hashMap using following code...

```
ClientRequest  clientRequest = new ClientRequest("MyserviveURL");
ClientResponse clientResponse = clientRequest.get(new GenericType <HashMap<String, Boolean>>(){});

HashMap myHash = (HashMap<String, Boolean>) clientResponse.getEntity();
```

I am getting error like Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for HashMap... Please help me to get out of this error.

And I also want to know about the best way to get the hashmap object from a client.. it can be via either xml or json

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson

user mapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(myHash);
```

And now return this `json` as "applicaton/json"

Comment: No... I am not using jackson... and I dont think it must be used to handle the situation ;)